# Which Ninjago set is this from?

Tags: set-identification, ninjago

[image]

Hi, if you can help me identify which set this is from that would be amazing!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing a bricklink search for "dragon window" allowed me to identify those stained glass windows as part [57895pb023](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57895pb023), which only appear in one set: [70728-1 Battle for Ninjago City](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70728-1)

[image: Set 70728]